# A single word for someone that makes a person up mentally definition

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone I know keeps making someone up and acts like "she" is real, like to know a word to define this.

Comment: Consider *imaginary friend*. As for the "someone" you know, you might say that they are *hallucinating*.

Comment: Also fantasist, one who creates fantasies.

Answer (score 3):

One such term is **tulpamancer**.

The term [tulpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulpa) applies to the more general notion of conjuring up something through sheer mental power.  This word has been adapted by many who work on creating imaginary friends.

Here is a community of tulpamancers asking each other questions : [tupla.info site](https://community.tulpa.info/thread-tulpamancer-noob-questions).

Here is a blog by a tulpamancer called [Alex and his imaginary friend Xerxes](http://xerxes-and-alex.tumblr.com/).

From [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulpa#Modern_perspective):

> These individuals, calling themselves "tulpamancers", belong to "primarily urban, middle class, Euro-American adolescent and young adult demographics" and they "cite loneliness and social anxiety as an incentive to pick up the practice." They report an improvement to their personal lives through the practice, and new unusual sensory experiences. Some practitioners have sexual and romantic interactions with their tulpa, though the practice is considered taboo. A survey of the community with 118 respondents on the explanation of tulpas found 8.5% support a metaphysical explanation, 76.5% support a neurological or psychological explanation, and 14% "other" explanations. Nearly all practitioners consider the tulpa a real or somewhat-real person.